# Extract values from a string with nested brackets

Tags: string, go

Given an input string such as:

`AB[C[DA,BF,GAL],DB[NX,AQQ,AAN,B],F[H[GG,BAND]]]`

Return an array of strings:

```
["ABCDA", "ABCBF", "ABCGAL", "ABDBNX", "ABDBAQQ", "ABDBAAN", "ABDBB", "ABFHGG"]
```

I was able to compose a partial solution, but it has trouble keeping track of the parent node if there are multiple `[children]`.

Another test string: `ZHLADAOR[R[G[45D[COI,EMA],Q5D[COI,EMA],U5D[COI,EMA],Y5D[COI,EMA]],HE5D[COI,EMA]],SG[A5D[COI,EMA],E5D[COI,EMA],I5D[COI,EMA]]]`

```golang
func expandNestedString(str string) []string {
    var parts []string
    var currentPart []rune
    var openBrackets int
    var level int
    var bitsBeforeComma int
    var prevBitsBeforeComma int

    for _, char := range str {
        if char == '[' {
            openBrackets++
            level++
            prevBitsBeforeComma = bitsBeforeComma
            bitsBeforeComma = 0
        } else if char == ']' {
            openBrackets--

            if openBrackets == 0 {
                if level == 0 && len(currentPart) > 0 {
                    parts = append(parts, string(currentPart))
                }
                currentPart = []rune{}
                level--
            } else {
                parts = append(parts, string(currentPart))
                currentPart = currentPart[:len(currentPart)-(bitsBeforeComma+prevBitsBeforeComma)]
                bitsBeforeComma = 0
            }
        } else if char == ',' {
            parts = append(parts, string(currentPart))
            currentPart = currentPart[:len(currentPart)-bitsBeforeComma]
            bitsBeforeComma = 0
        } else {
            currentPart = append(currentPart, char)
            bitsBeforeComma++
        }
    }

    if len(currentPart) > 0 {
        parts = append(parts, string(currentPart))
    }

    return parts
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally these sort of problems that seem to require balancing parentheses, or keeping track of pattern of previous characters can be done well with recursion. Here is a solution that works

```
func expand(s []rune, idx int) ([][]rune, int) {
    var prefix []rune
    var result [][]rune
    for ; idx < len(s); idx++ {
        switch s[idx] {
        case '[':
            runes, lastIdx := expand(s, idx+1)
            for _, r := range runes {
                result = append(result, append(prefix, r...))
            }
            idx = lastIdx
            prefix = []rune{}
        case ']':
            if len(prefix) > 0 {
                result = append(result, prefix)
            }
            return result, idx
        case ',':
            if len(prefix) > 0 {
                result = append(result, prefix)
                prefix = []rune{}
            }
        default:
            prefix = append(prefix, s[idx])
        }
    }
    if len(prefix) > 0 {
        result = append(result, prefix)
    }
    return result, idx
}

func expandNestedString(s string) []string {
    runes, _ := expand([]rune(s), 0)
    var result []string
    for _, r := range runes {
        result = append(result, string(r))
    }
    return result
}
```

in playground [here](https://play.golang.com/p/dLLqeBU6xGZ)

Comment: well done! Recursion was what I had in mind as well but my 1am brain wasn't up for the task :) great work. Another thing I was thinking about was constructing some kind of parent/child tree node system - every open bracket (without a terminating `]` bracket creates a parent node. Then, every time a comma or bracket terminator `]` is encountered, all of the previous nodes should be combined to yield an array part.

Comment: @user1111380 I was thinking the same but IMO since it is not used multiple times  constructing a tree might not be really useful